# Monitoring downloads of Google Cloud Storage objects that have public URLs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging

I have some objects in a Google Cloud Storage bucket that are publicly downloadable on URLs like https://storage.googleapis.com/blahblahblah. I want to set up a monitoring rule that lets me see how often one of these objects is being downloaded. I have turned on the Data Read audit log as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/guide-to-setting-up-monitoring-for-object-creation-in-cloud-storage), but I don't see any logs when I download the object from the storage.googleapis.com link. I have another bucket where downloads are performed through the Node Google Cloud Storage client library, and I can see download logs from that bucket, so it seems like downloads from the public URL don't get logged.

I also don't see a way to specify the object in a particular bucket when setting up an alert in Google Cloud. Is creating a new bucket solely for this object the best way to try to set up monitoring for the number of downloads, or is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Audit logs do not track objects that are public (`allUsers` or `allAuthenticatedUsers`).

Enable `usage logs` to track access to public objects.

[Should you use usage logs or Cloud Audit Logs?](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#should-you-use)